# Applescript Excel find percent and convert to number

Tags: excel, macos, applescript

I am starting with a spreadsheet that contains percentage data in non-adjacent cells. What I'm trying to do is create a script that finds all of the cells that contain data in percent format, then convert that data to a whole number (e.g., 45% becomes 45). My sheet also contains data formatted as general (i.e., N=125), so I need the script to differentiate the two types. Because of this I'm trying to make the script find the cells that contain a "%" sign, but I cannot get this to work.

Below are two options I've tried but neither works:

  1.

> set findData to (find (range "B:B" of active sheet) what "%" look at
>   part)

  2.

> ```
> set beginningRange to range "B1"
>    set findData to (get offset beginningRange row offset 1)
>    if value of findData contains "%" then
>        display dialog "found a %"
> ```

Does anyone have any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

IMO, for tasks that are totally within the Excel app, you are much better off using the Excel VBA.  You can even record a VBA macro doing the steps manually, and then edit that if need be.

There is no point in searching for cell contents containing a "%".  The "%" is part of the formatting, not part of the contents.

Steps to achieve your objective:

1. Search for cells that have the "Percentage" formatting
2. Change to General or number formatting
3. Multiply by 100

For an example, see [cells formatted as Percent which need to be automatically reformatted as (rounded up) whole numbers.](http://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28471087/How-to-automatically-find-and-convert-Percent-Formatted-Formula-Values-to-Whole-Number-Values-only-in-Excel.html)